# pdflatex error: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: errors, document-classes

I have a `settings.tex` file that looks like this:

```
\documentclass{letterpaper, 12pt, amsart}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

And I file `test.tex` that looks like:

```
\input{settings.tex}
\begin{document}
hi
\end{document}
```

When I run `pdflatex test.tex` I get an error saying I am missing `\begin{document}`. What gives?

Comment: Your documentclass is the problem. letterpaper and 12pt are optional arguments and should go in `[]`, so you need `\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{amsart}`

Comment: Thanks, godbless.

Comment: @HenkMetselaar Could you put your comment as an answer? This indeed seems to be the solution to the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your documentclass is the problem. letterpaper and 12pt are optional arguments and should go in [], so you need `\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{amsart}`